# When a link is clicked, grab the contents of another class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to take the Wordpress "reply" button for comments and making it grab the username of the comment you are replying to and post it into the comment textarea box like `@USERNAME`

Below is the output from my Wordpress comment. On line 6 there is a link that has a Class name `url` and the links text is `jasondavis`

Down farther down on line 15 there is the Reply link, it has a class of `comment-reply-link`

When a user clicks on that reply link, I am trying to get the Username in this case `jasondavis` so I can later insert it into the textarea box.

I think this can be done with jQuery, assume there are multiple of these comments on the page so when the Reply link is clicked, it has to be smart enough to get the text from `.url` but only from the `.url` that directly precedes the reply button for that particular comment that the reply button/link was clicked from.

If you have any tips or can help I would appreciate it

```
<li class="comment byuser comment-author-jasondavis bypostauthor even depth-2" id="comment-6">
    <div class="c-grav"><img alt="" src="http://1.gravatar.com/" class="avatar avatar-60 photo" height="60" width="60"></div>
    <div class="c-arrow"></div>
    <div class="c-body">
        <div class="c-head">
            <a href="http://www.codedevelopr.com/" rel="external nofollow" class="url">jasondavis</a>
            <span class="c-date">December 30, 2011 8:00pm</span>
        </div>
        <p>Comment body text is here......</p>

        <span class="edit-comment">
            <a class="comment-edit-link" href="" title="Edit comment">Edit</a>
            <a href="">Delete</a>
            <a href="">Spam</a>
            <a class="comment-reply-link" href="/codedevelopr/php-database-class/?replytocom=6#respond" onclick="return addComment.moveForm(&quot;comment-6&quot;, &quot;6&quot;, &quot;respond&quot;, &quot;5&quot;)">Reply</a>
        </span>
    </div><!--end c-body-->
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your comment `ul` has an ID of `comments`:

```
$("#comments").on('click', '.comment-reply-link', function(e) {
    var name = $(this).parents('.comment').first().find('.url').text();
    alert('replying to ' + name);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**[Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/wpAhJ/) on JSFiddle.**

Comment: This is awesome it shows me it is doable, I will have to play with it some but it's on the right track so thank you!  The issues I am having, is I also have threaded comments, so if a comment has 5 replies and I hit the reply button on the main comment, it will show the names from all 5 comments in a long string, if there is just 1 comment I am replying too, then it shows just the 1 name, so just got to figure out the kinks thanks a ton

Comment: @jasondavis: You should be able to add either `.first()` or `.last()` after `.find('.url')` to stop getting that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/W9JFv/) also on JSFiddle:

```
$(".comment-reply-link").click( function() { 
    username = $(this).parent().parent().children(".c-head").children(".url").html();   
    alert( username );
    return false; // to prevent further link processing by the browser.
});
```

To get value of the username, you have to walk through the tag nodes.

Comment: This works like icktoofay's example but without the problem I posted about in the comment for his, this seems to get around that problem and shows just the correct name, thank you!

Comment: I edited the code a little by adding: return false; to avoid the browser redirecting the page following through the link.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative that just works a little bit differently to .parents:

```
var name = $(this).closest('.comment').find('.url').text();
```

Comment: This works as well but has the same issue in my situation that I posted on @icktoofay's answer.  I realize I didn't post the code showing nested comments replies so that was my fault